# How do I increase the radius of a JavaFX PieChart

Tags: javafx, charts, pie-chart

I would like to increase the radius of a JavaFX pie chart because the default dimensions render a chart that is too small. I understand (from an answer posted by @ItachiUchiha 4 years ago) that it is impossible to directly manipulate the dimensions of a pie chart with a call like:

```
piechart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
piechart.setPrefHeight(600); // no effect
piechart.setPrefWidth(600); // no effect
```

The answer posted by @ItachiUchiha suggests using an instance of Region and indeed the following does achieve this:

```
Region region = new Region();
region.setMaxHeight(600);
region.setMaxWidth(600);
region.setPrefHeight(600);
region.setPrefWidth(600);
region.setMinHeight(600);
region.setMinWidth(600);
```

However I can't get the piechart into the instance of Region. Intuitively I tried:

```
region.getChildren().add(piechart);
and
Region region = new Region(piechart);
```

but these are syntactically wrong.

I know that the pie chart is rendering the Data properly because it displays ok with the code:

```
detailPane.getChildren().add(piechart);
piechart.setVisible(true);
```

But this just renders the pie chart with its default radius. How to I 'link' the pie chart to the instance of Region and get it to resize as required?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have solved the issue through .css by adding the following to the stylesheet:

```
.chart {
    -fx-pref-width: 916;
    -fx-pref-height: 620; 
    -fx-min-width: 916;
    -fx-min-height: 620;
    -fx-max-width: 916;
    -fx-max-height: 620;
}

.chart-content {
    -fx-padding: 20px;
}
```

The chart dimensions exactly match the anchorpane size of the right hand split pane. The result is a very nicely sized and well proportioned pie chart centered exactly in the pane.